# Why does my MAC address reset after reconnecting?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, mac-address

I use Ubuntu 12. I'm changing my MAC address with `ifconfig wlan0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, which works. However when I restart my connection, my computer resets the MAC address to my original MAC address. I'm guessing that this happens because something calls...

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
... do something before connecting
ifconfig wlan0 up
... connect to designated access point
```

- I want my MAC address to be the same no matter how many times I disconnect and reconnect, whether to another network or the same one.
- Also it would be nice to turn off the auto-connect feature for my network-manager without having to edit each individual connection.
- Lastly I would like to know how to connect to a WiFi network through the terminal and not via the GUI network manager Ubuntu provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my mac address to however be the same

Try: right-click on network manager applet, "Edit Connections ...", choose (or create) a connection, "Edit", type a value into "MAC Address" box. These instructions are from 10.04.

> Lastly I would like to know how to connect to a wifi network through the terminal

Look at [`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/interfaces.5.html) and the commands [`ifdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ifdown.8.html) and [`ifup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ifup.8.html).